# Pass variables with url in php as I am integrating payment gateway in wordpress of payu

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway

```
 $url = 'https.secure.payu.in/_payment';
```

I want to pass the variables to the that site.  like merchant key and
other variables values. How I  have to approach this.

And values I have passed like this

```
$post_values = array(
    "key" => pmpro_getOption("payu_merchantid")
);
```

as of now I am passing the URL Like this

```
wp_redirect($url);
```

Please give me proper idea for this.

Comment: i think you have to use curl instead of direct redirecting on payment gateway?

Comment: yes that way only could you please write the code of that as answer. I have added code previously in this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613891/how-to-redirect-to-the-url-after-defining-some-variables-with-curl-init?noredirect=1#comment25638858_17613891 like this